# Добавление QComboBox в ячейку QTableWidget при изменении количества строк таблицы

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, pyqt6

Предположим у нас есть таблица `QTableWidget`. Мы хотим автоматически по кнопке добавлять в неё строки.

В **`1`** столбце всегда должен образовываться заранее подготовленный список `QComboBox`.

Я реализовал данный алгоритм, однако почему то во всех предыдущих строках ячейка первого столба становится недоступной, выпадающий список остаётся только в последней строки.

А если и вовсе попытаться наоборот уменьшить количество строк, то программа выдаст ошибку:

> RunTimeError:  wrapped C/C++ object of type QComboBox has been deleted.

Наглядно изобразил на [картинке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig6a3.png).

За таблицу отвечает переменная `table_test`, за ввод количества строк `rowc`

**func.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import Frame

class InputsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(InputsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Frame.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # adding check box in table
    self.cbx_schreg = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Устье")
    self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Протяжённая часть")
    self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Сопряжение")

    self.ui.rowc.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.ui.table_test.setRowCount(val))
    self.ui.rowc.valueChanged.connect(self.set_section)

def set_section(self):
    self.ui.table_test.setCellWidget(self.ui.table_test.rowCount() - 1, 0, self.cbx_schreg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = Frame.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    Form = InputsWindow()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Код UI **Frame.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.mainLayout.setObjectName("mainLayout")
    self.table_test = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.table_test.setObjectName("table_test")
    self.table_test.setColumnCount(2)
    self.table_test.setRowCount(1)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table_test.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table_test.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table_test.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.table_test, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.rowc = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.rowc.setObjectName("rowc")
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.rowc, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    item = self.table_test.verticalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
    item = self.table_test.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "col1"))
    item = self.table_test.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "col2"))
```

Если у кого то будет желание написать, то ещё интересно как можно реализовывать несколько виджетов в ячейке `QTableWidget`. Например `QLabel` + `QCheckBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект `cbx_schreg` не должен быть атрибутом класса. Попробуйте так:

```
#from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui                         # from PyQt6
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui                          # from PyQt5

#from Frame import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setObjectName("mainLayout")
        self.table_test = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_test.setObjectName("table_test")
        self.table_test.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_test.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_test.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_test.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_test.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.table_test, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rowc = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.rowc.setObjectName("rowc")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.rowc, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.table_test.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.table_test.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "col1"))
        item = self.table_test.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "col2"))


class InputsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InputsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

#        # adding check box in table
#        self.cbx_schreg = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
#        self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Устье")
#        self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Протяжённая часть")
#        self.cbx_schreg.addItem("Сопряжение")

#        self.ui.rowc.valueChanged.connect(
#            lambda val: self.ui.table_test.setRowCount(val))
            
        self.ui.rowc.valueChanged.connect(self.set_section)

    def set_section(self, val):
        self.ui.table_test.model().removeRows(0, val)
      
        if not val:
            self.ui.table_test.model().removeRow(0)
            return
        
        self.ui.table_test.setRowCount(val)
        for row in range(val):
            cbx_schreg = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            cbx_schreg.addItems([f"Устье {row}", "Протяжённая часть", "Сопряжение"])
            
            self.ui.table_test.setCellWidget(row, 0, cbx_schreg)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    Form = InputsWindow()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо! Я понял суть проблемы =)

Comment: @AddmiX  пожалуйста. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.