# Иконка программы PyQt6 в панеле задач после упаковки в exe через pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqt6, qrc, windowicon

В попытках установить иконку своей программе в панели задач так и не пришёл к положительному результату. На базе моего предыдущего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344356/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-qcombobox-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-qtablewidget-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86) задам новый:

Что нужно сделать, дабы иконка отображалась в панеле задач самостоятельного исполняемого файла?

---

Так как в **`PyQt6`** отсуствует поддержка **`pyrcc`**, то я использую следующие команды чтобы файлы иконок были загружены в **.exe**:

```
QtCore.QDir.addSearchPath('icons', 'resources/')
icon = QtGui.QIcon("icons:icon.png")
```

Для того, чтобы Windows не ставил иконку по умолчанию, реализую `ctypes`:

```
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

После этого я задаю иконку:

```
app = Frame.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

Также, в файле **.spec** указывается каталог `resources`:

```
datas=[ ('/full_path/Main/resources' , 'resources') ],
```

После компиляции иконка не отображается в панели задачи, вместо неё стандартная иконка программ *Windows*.

Сама [иконка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VjiJ.png).

И как это выглядит при запуске из **`PyCharm`**:

[image: PyCharm]

И самостоятельный **.exe**:

[image: exe]

Минимальный воспроизводимый код `ui` можно взять в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344356/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-qcombobox-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-qtablewidget-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86).

Comment: AddmiX, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128075 может поможет.

Comment: Да, я пробовал ваш вариант в том вопросе прежде чем задать свой, однако судя по всему в 6 версии PyQt отсуствует `QtWinExtras`

Comment: Забыл упоминуть про `ctypes`, вопрос дополнил

Comment: фактически, метод, представленный в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105 вопросе на Windows 10 21H1 не помогает

Comment: @AddmiX привет, я также задал вопрос, и также убедился(спасибо S.Nick за подсказку), в PyQt6 был рефакторинг, и QtWinExtras был перенесен и переименован, почитать можно [тут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/extras-changes-qt6.html). И также заметилЭ, что если билдить с консолью, то на консоли висит иконка.

Comment: Решил потестить и на решении с PyQt5, но столкнулся с этим - `PyQt5.QtWinExtras.QtWin represents a C++ namespace and cannot be instantiated`